# Jupyter notebooks in VSCode not showing up to date python kernel list

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, virtualenv

For a couple of months I've had issues with working with virtual envs, python notebooks & jupyter in VSCode, for some reason, a lot of the time, it cannot find kernels I added, even though I can see them when running `jupyter kernelspec list`. It seems random whether they appear or not. Reloading the screen and restarting vscode does not help, neither does disabling and re-enabling the python and jupyter extensions. I tried both from the button, select kernel and through the command palette. I usually start vscode from the command line, with my virtual environment activated. Moreover, a lot of kernels which I've deleted a long time ago still show up in the list.
Vscode and laptop are both up to date.
I've had issues with the integrated jupyter notebooks before, at first formatting and autocomplete didn't work in the notebook (but they did in regular python files).
I'm on MacOS, if that matters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry to tell that this is a bug, see bug report:
[Can't see or select Jupyter kernel's from Kernel drop-down](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/7706)

And now there's a workaround that:

> - Find where python is installed
> - Select the command Python: Select Interpreter
>
>   - Next select Enter interpreter path
>   - Next enter the path into the input box and hit Enter
>
> This interpretr will now work in VS Code and you might need to re-load
> VS Code just once more to get it working in jupyter extension.

Please have a try.

Comment: When I enter this path in the input box, nothing happens.

Comment: What does select the command mean?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue - it was present when I had created a 'portable' version of VSCode due to the OS restrictions on Remote Access, after previously accessing a remote VSCode server with a higher (and unsupported) version.

My solution was:

- Delete all offending extensions (in this case Jupyter)
- Open a Notebook file (this prompts a 'Suggested Extension' drop down)
- Install the suggested extension
- Reload window